# SpamAssassin (spamd) server is taking too long to respond?

Tags: spamassassin

I have two servers with an instance of Spamd running on both of them.

When I connect to one server via Telnet, and run a command, the SA server responds almost instantly.

But the second server takes about 23 seconds to respond, and close the communication right after.

I tried restarting the process, and also restarted the server, but the problem stays.

The installation for the servers are the same as far as I can tell and the two servers are physically identical.

Here's the command run (as displayed by `service spamassassin status`) :

/usr/bin/perl -T -w /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid --create-prefs --max-children 5 --helper-home-dir -i 10.0.1.10 -A 10.0.1.0/24

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please check the logs under /var/log/ directory. One possible reason that immediately comes to my mind would be that if your SpamAssassin is using BerkeleyDB or similar as a backend for anything, it could be that due a failed shutdown there still would be lock files around and a proper use of `db_recover` would fix the issue. But, since I don't yet know anything else about your environment other than what you posted, not going to reply any longer yet.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, happy to help. Do you need any specific log ?

Comment: Well it's all up to which distribution you use and how the syslog is configured, but many times /var/log/mail.log or similar also contains SpamAssassin related errors. Of course it's perfectly possible you have a separate log for SpamAssassin there.